# Pipe with error events

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, error-handling, stream

When building complex stream pipelines, it often makes sense to pass errors from one stage to the next. (In the situation at hand, I'm considering Gulp pipelines.) But apparently the Node.js stream `pipe` method doesn't do that.

One can manually bind the error event listener of one stream to the error event emitter of the next. But that's pretty tedious.

Is there some easy way to build pipelines with error chaining? Or is there some reason why one shouldn't do this?

Example:

```
var through = require("through2");

var s1 = through(function(chunk, enc, cb) {
    console.log("In 1: " + chunk.toString());
    cb(null, chunk);
});
var s2 = through(function(chunk, enc, cb) {
    console.log("In 2: " + chunk.toString());
    if (chunk.toString() === "error")
        cb(Error("Something broke"), null);
    else
        cb(null, chunk);
});
var s3 = through(function(chunk, enc, cb) {
    console.log("In 3: " + chunk.toString());
    cb(null, chunk);
});

s1.pipe(s2).pipe(s3)
    .on("data", function(chunk, enc) {
        console.log("Out: " + chunk.toString());
    })
    .on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("Final error: " + err);
    })
;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The following two lines are the relevant part. //
s1.on("error", s2.emit.bind(s2, "error"));        //
s2.on("error", s3.emit.bind(s3, "error"));        //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

s1.write("first");
s1.write("error");
s1.write("last");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some easy way to build pipelines with error chaining?

[bubble-stream-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bubble-stream-error) provides a mechanism to do this.

> Or is there some reason why one shouldn't do this?

Not that I'm aware of. This seems like something you would reasonably want to do in many cases.